# Como crear pdf en php y mysql

Tags: php

No se como trabajar con la creacion de pdf

Teniendo en cuenta estos campos
 `$conector =" SELECT nombre, descripcion, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio FROM materiales";`

**pdfplantilla.php**

```
<?php

    require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

    class PDF extends FPDF
    {
        function Header()
        {
            // $this->Image('images/logo.png', 5, 5, 30 );
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            $this->Cell(30);
            $this->Cell(120,10, 'Reporte De Estados',0,0,'C');
            $this->Ln(20);
        }

        function Footer()
        {
            $this->SetY(-15);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','I', 8);
            $this->Cell(0,10, 'Pagina '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C' );
        }       
    }
?>
```

**pdfReporte.php**

```
<?php
    include 'pdfPlantilla.php';
    require '../configuracion/conexion.php';

    $query = "SELECT nombre, descripcion, cantidad FROM materiales";      
    // $query = "SELECT e.estado, m.id_municipio, m.municipio FROM t_municipio AS m INNER JOIN t_estado AS e ON m.id_estado=e.id_estado";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $pdf->Cell(70,6,'nombre',1,0,'C',1);
    $pdf->Cell(20,6,'descripcion',1,0,'C',1);
    // $pdf->Cell(70,6,'cantidad',1,1,'C',1);
    // $pdf->Cell(70,6,'precio',1,1,'C',1);

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $pdf->Cell(70,6,$row['nombre'],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,$row['descripcion'],1,0,'C');
        // $pdf->Cell(70,6,$row['cantidad'],1,1,'C');
        // $pdf->Cell(70,6,$row['precio'],1,1,'C');

    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

El error que tengo es este :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error:
>   Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\comunal\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\comunal\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some
>   data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\www\comunal\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php(999):
>   FPDF->_checkoutput() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\comunal\pdf\pdfReporte.php(30): FPDF->Output() #3
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\comunal\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line
>   271 –

Answer (score 1):

Este error puede ocurrir porque se escribió algo y, **para que FPDF funcione correctamente, no debe haber ninguna salida** (que no sea lo que el propio FPDF genera). Es un error similar a lo que ocurre si intentas redirigir con `header` una vez se ha escrito algo.

El código que compartes parece que está bien a simple vista, pero debes asegurarte que:

- **Evita escribir por pantalla** (con `echo`, `var_dump`, `print`, etc...). No se ve nada de esto en tu código, por lo que no es relevante en tu caso, pero es una causa común.
- **Asegúrate de que no hay errores en consultas SQL**. Si por cualquier motivo, tu consulta SQL o la conexión a la base de datos falla, entonces PHP mostrará un error y eso causará que FPDF falle con ese mensaje.
- **No tengas espacios al principio**. Por ejemplo, evita cosas como ésta:

  ```
   <?php
  ```

  Si te fijas, hay un espacio en blanco justo antes de la llave `<?php`, eso hará que FPDF falle porque ya ha habido una salida (ese espacio en blanco) que no es de FPDF.
- **No tengas espacios al final**. Esto puede ser más difícil de ver:

  ```
  ?>
  ```

  Efectivamente no se ve nada, pero hay un espacio en blanco justo después del `?>` que hará que FPDF lance ese error. Esto se puede solucionar eliminando el `?>` en páginas que van a ser sólo PHP, así si hay algún espacio en blanco al final, directamente se ignorará (y no es necesario cerrar la etiqueta de PHP al final)

En tu caso particular, el código se ve bien a simple vista y no se ven espacios en blanco (quizás no los copiaste). Por eso me estoy imaginando que el problema está en la conexión a la base de datos/consulta SQL.